# Facebook Open Graph Debugger can't scrape .tools domain?

Tags: facebook, graph

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://responsive.tools

Trying to scrape with Facebook Debugger tool, I wondered that Facebook is not capable to scrape my new website.

Do you have any insight for helping me find solution?
Thank you, Fabio.